# Runnable run() function terminates immediately

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm currently trying to multithread a previous program of mine. Here is the code below:

```
public class DipoleTester {
  public static String DIR = "/home/";
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Dipole trial;
    ExecutorService service = 
       Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    for (int r = 10; r < 150; r += 1) {
      double radius = (double) r / 10000.0;
      for (int matType = 0; matType < 3; matType++) {
        String name = matType + "_rad" + radius;
        trial = new DipoleSimple(DIR, name);
        trial.materialType = matType;
        trial.RADIUS = radius;
        service.submit(trial);
      }
    }
    service.shutdown();
    service.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.HOURS);
  }
}
```

It's a pretty straightforward program. run() is just a pretty basic method that used to be the main() method. On average it takes about 3 minutes to evaluate. The problem is that here, it seems like it's just making an asynchronous call to run() because it evaluates the entire threadpool instantly.

i.e. i'm expecting it to run say  8 threads in parallel in 3-5 minutes. But instead, it runs each one and says it's completed practially instantly and loads up the next thread in the threadpool. So I'm left with a couple hundred threads that are all trying to run simultaneously.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: i think it would help to watch thread behavior with some tool like JVisualVM. Maybe a thread dump? and probably it would also be helpful to see the run() method.

Comment: Have you tried submitting a dummy instead? Just with a Thread.sleep( sometime) in it?

Comment: So your `DipoleSimple.run()` method takes 3 minutes to evaluate?  You sure something else isn't going on because the code looks good.  Can you post a sample of the `DipoleSimple` class?

Comment: It's a little long, so i won't be able to paste it. But the run() method makes a bunch of calls to a physics simulation API (Comsol) which is why it takes so long.I suspect that the API may be setup to run asynchronously. But before when I ran the DipoleTester class without any sort of multithreading (i.e. run N trials) it would do them sequentially/blocking. So I am skeptical that is the reason why.

Comment: You have answered the question: the tasks are creating threads. That is why you are left with hundreds of them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, I tried following sample to test it out:

```
System.out.println("Available Processors: "+Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        final AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            es.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+"_"+ai.incrementAndGet());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        System.out.println("shutting down");
        es.shutdown();
        System.out.println("shutdown");
        es.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        System.out.println("Completed");
```

Sample output (consider 4 available processor):

```
Available Processors: 4
pool-1-thread-2_1
pool-1-thread-3_3
pool-1-thread-4_4
pool-1-thread-1_2
shutting down
shutdown
pool-1-thread-2_5
pool-1-thread-4_6
pool-1-thread-3_7
pool-1-thread-1_8
pool-1-thread-2_9
pool-1-thread-4_10
Completed
```

Since you are not submitting additional trials after `shutdown`, all submitted trials must be getting processed as you can see above all 10 threads submitted before `shutdown` completes. You can verify this by logging `run` method completion log/statement. Further it would be helpful to analyze if you can add time logs as how much time `run` method is taking by each thread when you run your actual code.

Comment: `shutdown` does not interrupt running threads.

Comment: @jtahlborn thanks for pointing this out, you are right, interruption happens for any worker threads that might be blocked in `getTask` internally as per internal comments in `ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdown`. Edited my response.

Comment: shutdown only stops any additional tasks to be submitted.  All tasks submitted will run.

Comment: Also, you are confusing tasks and threads in your answer.  -1